# How to check whether the user touching the screen or not, within 5 seconds

Tags: android, timer, ontouchlistener

I want to count 5 seconds in an activity and check whether the user is touching any part of the screen or not , if the user is not touching within 5 seconds , then i want to show this. How can i do that ??

```
Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "No action taken within 5 seconds ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
```

Comment: Count timer and set this layout Parent view's id ontouch method

Comment: can you show me the answer with some code ?@IntelliJAmiya

Comment: @JaisonJoseph  Do you want to show it only once or every 5 seconds?

Comment: Only once is enough

Comment: @JaisonJoseph check my answer . for Once . Declare boolean value .if value==true then cancel

Comment: I did not understand this , where should i add this ?  implements View.OnTouchListener{

Answer (score 4):

At first Call this in your `onCreate()` section

```
    LinearLayout mLinearLayoutMain = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.your_id); // Set your Layout
    mLinearLayoutMain.setOnTouchListener(this);
    startTimer();
```

Make sure your activity **implements** below

```
implements View.OnTouchListener{
```

**startTimer()**

```
public void startTimer() {
        //set a new Timer
        timer = new Timer();

        //initialize the TimerTask's job
        initializeTimerTask();

        //schedule the timer, after the first 10000ms the TimerTask will run every 10 seconds
        timer.schedule(timerTask, 10000, 10000); //
    }
```

**Then**

```
public void cancelTask() {
    //stop the timer, if it's not already null
    if (timer != null) {
        timer.cancel();
        timer = null;
        Log.d("cancel","Amiyo");

        startTimer();;
        Log.d(" startTimer","Amiyo");
    }
}

public void initializeTimerTask() {

    timerTask = new TimerTask() {
        public void run() {

            //use a handler to run a toast that shows the current timestamp
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"No action taken within 5 seconds ",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });
        }
    };
}

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event)
{
    Log.d("Hi","Touching");
    cancelTask();

    return false;//false indicates the event is not consumed
}
```

**Global Declare**

```
Timer timer;
TimerTask timerTask;

//we are going to use a handler to be able to run in our TimerTask
final Handler handler = new Handler();
```

Comment: @user7345006 just a logic .Thanks

Comment: I did not understand this , where should i add this ?  implements View.OnTouchListener{

Comment: u mean my mainactivity ??

Comment: my contant_main.xml is Relative layout and activity_main.xml is CoordinatorLayout , so what to do @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: unfortunately yes!!

Comment: the toast is cumming in every 5 seconds even in fragment, what to do ??@IntelliJAmiya

Comment: actually i want to show it once, when the user is in the front window of my app @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: sorry i don't don't know how to use boolean for this :(@IntelliJAmiya

Comment: i am waiting for your help @IntelliJAmiya

Comment: are you there @IntelliJAmiya